# Which Hindu episode does this Khmer relief from Beng Mealea show?

Tags: identification-request

[image]

The person below the main relief is considered a man lying in the water. It is conjectured that he is Shyavana, a sage meditating in a holy river.

What is the story about him? Where is the story told? Which persons are on top of the relief?

**Note**. Beng Mealea translated from Khmer language means "lotos pond".

Comment: I think they refer to the Rshi known as Chyavana: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyavana

Comment: @user1952500 Are you sure? Because I do not find in his myth any episode where he is in the water. The relief shows water, neither an ant-hill nor a hole in the earth.

Comment: Regarding the water episode, Chyavana takes a dip in a pond and is cured of blindness, but three Chyavanas arise from the water, and the wife is asked to pick out the right one (two are Ashwinis in disguise).

Comment: @user1952500 You are right concerning a water episode in the story of Chyavana, either for curing blindness or for regaining youth and strenght. But don't you miss at least the Ashwins and Sukanya if the person is Chyavana?

Comment: There is a story in mahabharata where its mentioned that Rishi Chavana did tapas under water for 12 years , only  if we know for sure this man is chavana.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Do you know a precise reference in the MB concerning "12 years under water"? I found only the story about juvenation. - One tries to find out the name of the person from Beng Melea by identifying the episode displayed on the relief.

Comment: @JoWehler Yes , i know exact ref. with all details. Will give you in some time .:-)

Comment: @JoWehler Its in Anushasana parva - "O Chief of Bharata's race, the great Rishi Chyavana of Bhrigu's race, always observant of high vows, became desirous of leading for some time the mode of life called Udavasa and set himself to commence it. Casting off pride and wrath and joy and grief, the ascetic, pledging himself to observe that vow, set himself to live for twelve years according to the rules of Udavasa. The Rishi inspired all creatures with a happy trust. And he inspired similar confidence in all creatures living in water."http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b015.htm

Comment: @JoWehler उदवास m. udavAsa - residence in water - http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=udAvas&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3 I have also checked Hindi translation , its correct , he was living under water of ganga and yamuna. :-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Many thanks for finding out the story from MB. If you convert your comment into an answer I would like to upvote and to accept your answer :-)

Comment: @JoWehler - Yes ,  I will write an answer , but before that let me again check whether the full story is present anywhere else.Thanks.

Comment: @JoWehler Btw I just found out that there is one more rishi who did  Austerities under water .

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Great: The mysterious relief gets more and more interesting ...

Comment: @JoWehler:An interesting question. upvoted

Comment: @JoWehler There is also one another person - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amba_(Mahabharata) - Who did tapasya under water in the yamuna river. Amba performing tapasya under water is also mentioned in Mahabharata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  Beng Mealea relief image is showing an  ascetic lying under ground or  probably underwater performing tapas or penance. There are many ways mentioned in Hinduism scriptures with which one can perform tapas or penance. For e.g. living only on air , Standing on one foot in meditation , surviving only on dry leaves etc.

Similarly ascetics  doing Tapasya under ground  or water are class of ascetics named as **Unmajjakas** - The Submerged as mentioned in [**Baudhāyana Dharma Sutras**](https://archive.org/details/DharmasutrasTheLawCodesOfApastambaGautamaBaudhayanaAndVasistha/page/n259) -Page 214.

Mahabharata calling this act as mode  of life - [**Udavasa . उदवास**](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=udAvas&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3)    - UdavAsa   or residence in water. In this  Udavasa vow a person sometimes can also come out of water  of river or pond and stand up on legs.

The  names of  two  Rishis  who were  Unmajjakas  or   Udavasakas for some years are  mentioned  in Hinduism scriptures  mainly Mahabharata and Vishnu Purana those were -  **Rishi Chavana and Rishi Saubhari.**

---

In [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b015.htm)- Anushasana Parva-Chapter 50 , there is mention of an account of Rishi Chavana observing Udavasa vow for twelve years.

> पुरा महर्षिश्चवनो भार्गवो भरतर्षभ |
>  उदवास कृतारम्भो बभूव स महाव्रत
>   : || 3 ||
>  निहत्य मानं क्रोधं च प्रहर्षं शोकमेव च |
>  वर्षाणि
>   द्वादशा  मुनिर्जलवासे धृतव्रत : || 4 ||
>
> "Bhishma said, 'I shall, in this connection, O thou of great
>   effulgence, recite to thee an ancient narrative of a conversation
>   between Nahusha and the Rishi Chyavana. In days of yore O Chief of
>   Bharata's race, the great Rishi Chyavana of Bhrigu's race, always
>   observant of high vows, became desirous of leading for some time the
>   mode of life called Udavasa and set himself to commence it. Casting
>   off pride and wrath and joy and grief, the ascetic, pledging himself
>   to observe that vow, set himself to live for twelve years according to
>   the rules of Udavasa. The Rishi inspired all creatures with a happy
>   trust. And he inspired similar confidence in all creatures living in
>   water. The puissant ascetic resembled the Moon himself in his
>   behaviour to all. Bowing unto all the deities and having cleansed
>   himself of all sins, he entered the water at the confluence of the
>   Ganga and the Yamuna, and stood there like an inanimate post of wood.
>   Placing his head against it, he bore the fierce and roaring current of
>   the two streams united together,--the current whose speed resembled
>   that of the wind itself. The Ganga and the Yamuna, however, and the
>   other streams and lakes, whose waters unite together at the confluence
>   at Prayaga, instead of afflicting the Rishi, went past him (to show
>   him respect).
>
> स्थाणुभूत : शुचिर्भूत्वा दैवतेभ्य : प्रणम्य च | 
>  गंगायमुनोर्मध्ये
>   **जलं संप्रविवेश** ह || 6 ||
>
> Assuming the attitude of a wooden post, **the great Muni sometimes
>   laid himself P. 39 down in the water and slept at ease.** And
>   sometimes, O chief of Bharata's race, the intelligent sage stood in an
>   erect posture. He became quite agreeable unto all creatures living in
>   water. Without the least fear, all these used to smell the Rishi's
>   lips. In this way, the Rishi passed a long time at that grand
>   confluence of waters.

---

**Brief Story - :** There is a story associated with Rishi Chavana living under water for observing this vow. As mentioned earlier Chavana Muni was once observing a vow Called  Udavasa and was living under water for 12 years. Once in between , when he was laying underwater some fishermen came at the spot to catch the fish. They laid out the net along with the river. Maharshi Chavana being underwater also got caught in those nets along with the fish. The fishermen feared seeing that they pulled rishi out of water . Rishi Chavana told them that he will defend those fish and he will either live or die with the fish. 
Hearing the saying of the Rishi the fishermen got very afraid and went to king  Nahusha for the solution. Upon coming to King Chavana asked King Nahusha to pay the price of the caught along with him also to fishermen . The fishermen requests to pay 1000 Nishkas to Nahusha , but Chavana argues that this 1000 Nishkas are not the justified worth of he himself and asks king to give something other than that. King Nahusha then accepts to give away half of his kingdom to fishermen , but again Chavana says that his half of the kingdom is also not the rightful value of himself. After consulting with Brahmanas king Nahusha gave  away a cow as a value of the catch and Chavana both to fishermen. The fishermen then gives that cow as a donation to Rishi and being satisfied with that donation of a single cow Chavana sends the fishermen to heaven. The Moral of the story is importance of Donation of the cow and how Godana is more valuable than all the other donations,

Rishi Chavana laying underwater for Tapasya is part of the above story. But the Purpose of this Udavasa wow is also mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b022.htm). But Rishi Chavana being great Rishi did not even wanted that and didn't performed this vow for being lord of Heaven.

उदवासं वसेत यस्तु स नराधिपतिर्भवेत ||18 ||

P. 56 One who passes some time in that mode of life which is called Udavasa, becomes the very lord of Heaven.

---

## Rishi Saubhari

Now there is one more Rishi called Saubhari  who also spent 12 years underwater in penance who is  mentioned in [**Vishnu Purana**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp094.htm) - Book 4 - Chapter 2

> P.363 **The devout sage Saubhari, learned in the Vedas, had spent twelve
>   years immersed in a piece of water;** the sovereign of the fish in
>   which, named Sammada, of large bulk, had a very numerous progeny. His
>   children and his grandchildren were wont to frolic around him in all
>   The Story in brief - Once Rishi Saubhari had spend twelve years
>   immersed inside water performing tapasya. Once when he was underwater
>   he saw sporting / mating of fish and playing with their offspring. By
>   seeing this scene he also desired to got married and have children and
>   then he decided to marry daughters of king  Mándhátri. Even though he
>   was performing server tapas ,his mind got diverted from that even
>   looking at the sports of the fish.

The moral of the story is how a person's mind gets disturbed and gets involved in sexual desires , even watching mating of the fish in the water.

---

The story of Rishi Saubhari is also mentioned in Srimad Bhagavata  purana as downfall of Rishi  Saubhari and warns us about how our mind gets attracted towards material desires , just by looking at outside world. And teaches a lesson  to keep very tight  firmness of mind while performing tapasya to those who are doing it.

> स कदाचिदुपासीन आत्मापह्नवमात्मन: ।
>  ददर्श बह्वृचाचार्यो
>   मीनसङ्गसमुत्थितम् ॥ [**9.6.49**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/6/49/) ॥
>
> sa kadācid upāsīna ātmāpahnavam ātmanaḥ
>  dadarśa bahv-ṛcācāryo
>   mīna-saṅga-samutthitam
>
> Thereafter, one day while Saubhari Muni, who was expert in chanting
>   mantras, was sitting in a secluded place, he thought to himself about
>   the cause of his fall down, which was simply that he had associated
>   himself with the sexual affairs of the fish.
>
> ---
>
> अहो इमं पश्यत मे विनाशं तपस्विन: सच्चरितव्रतस्य ।
>  अन्तर्जले
>   वारिचरप्रसङ्गात् प्रच्यावितं ब्रह्म चिरं धृतं यत् ॥  [**9.6.50**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/6/50/)  ॥
>
> aho imaṁ paśyata me vināśaṁ tapasvinaḥ sac-carita-vratasya
>   antarjale vāri-cara-prasaṅgāt pracyāvitaṁ brahma ciraṁ dhṛtaṁ yat
>
> **Alas! While practicing austerity, even within the depths of the water,**
>   and while observing all the rules and regulations practiced by saintly
>   persons, I lost the results of my long austerities simply by
>   association with the sexual affairs of fish. Everyone should observe
>   this falldown and learn from it.

---

So it is quite possible that the relief in your question is either of Rishi Chavana or Rishi Saubhari , both who laid down  under water for tapasya. And the persons standing above them probably are the disciples of them .

Comment: good answer. i admire your knowledge@SwiftPushkar

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Thanks - Haha Believe me I am not that knowledgeable as you are thinking. Just a ordinary one , like you all guys.